# When I upload my extension in magento marketplace it show "Failed to open file composer.json. Please verify the archive"

Tags: magento2, marketplace

When I upload  my extension  in magento marketplace it show  "Failed to open file composer.json. Please verify the archive".

[image]

> composer.json

```
{
  "name": "magento/sample-module-newpage",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates a new page",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~7.1.3|~7.2.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Magento\\SampleNewPage\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Reference : https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/create-composer-json-file-to-upload-magento-2-extension-to-marketplace/

Comment: Make sure your module and composer files are placed in root location of your archive file.